# unable to remove stopwords;NLP

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stop-words, multiclass-classification

I have csv file which contains 2 column 'Complaint Details' and 'DispositionCode'.I want to **classify** the complaintDetails into **8 different classes** of dispostionCode such as 'Door locked from inside','Vendor error','Missing key or lock'...
The dataset is shown in the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPdR1.png)

**What would be good method to classify and find accuracy.**

Initially I am trying with removing **stopwords** from the ComplaintDetails and then use **naivebayes classifier**

The code is as follows:

```
import csv
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
your_list=[]
with open('H:/Project/rash.csv', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  your_list = list(reader)
print(your_list)
stop_words=set(stopwords.words("english"))
words= word_tokenize(your_list)
filteredSent=[]
for w in words:
    if w not in stop_words:
       filteredSent.append()
print(filteredSent)
```

But I am getting following error:-

**for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object**

Comment: `word_tokenize` takes a string as an argument not a list of strings.  Call `word_tokenize` on each element in `your_list` not on `your_list` itself.

Comment: It's a list of lists (csv file rows), so it needs double unpacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code never gets to the stopwords, since the error is due to misusing `word_tokenize()`. It needs to be called on a single string, not on your whole dataset. You can tokenize your data like this:

```
for row in your_list:
    row[0] = word_tokenize(row[0])
```

You'll now need to rethink the rest of your code. You have a whole list of sentences, not just one. Use a loop like the above so you're examining the words of one sentence at a time.

Comment: thank you !! it worked for me.@ alexis .But Can you tell me the method I am using to classify i.e naiveBayes classifier will work here??

Comment: I cannot. You have to try it, measure the performance, and decide what to do next.